# Protect root volume for AMIs with product code

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-marketplace

we found that it is possible to take a snapshot of the root volume of an AMI with a Marketplace product code. From this snapshot it is easy to create a new AMI (this one has the product code), or mount it on a new instance and copy the content to another volume and create an AMI from it without the product code.

I like to be able to protect any installed proprietary software on the AMI against reverse engineering (reading) and prevent impersonating an instance-id with a product code from one that has been tampered with. We've read many different articles on the subject and have not found a way to prevent this without getting 'identity view' permission of the owner of the instance. Any suggestions are most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as a seller, you cannot prevent buyers in AWS Marketplace from accessing your AMI contents.

The AWS Marketplace policy requires the following:

> AMIs must allow operating system (OS)-level administration capabilities to allow for compliance requirements, vulnerability updates, and log file access. Linux-based AMIs use SSH, and Windows-based AMIs use RDP.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/latest/userguide/product-and-ami-policies.html#accessibility